# Prevent DIV from becoming too small when resizing window with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm using vh to set height of divs and vw to set their width.

Is there any way to prevent a DIV from becoming too small when resizing the browser window using pure HTML and CSS only?

Comment: There are many resources on the web regarding this. In short, it depends on your browser compatibility list to some extend, especially regarding vertical size.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in css:

```
div {
 min-width: 200px; /*Says that the every div has at least to be 200px width*/
 min-height: 200px; /*Says that the every div has at least to be 200px height*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id='minWidth'></div>

#minWidth{
   min-width: 200px;
}
```

For more information check out:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

this can also be set for height

```
#minHeight{
   min-height: 200px;
}
```